# How to connect express js from azure function Model v4?

Tags: node.js, typescript, express, azure-functions

My azure function using Model v4

index.ts

```
import { app } from "@azure/functions";
import azureFunctionHandler from "azure-aws-serverless-express";
import expressApp from "../../app";

app.http("httpTrigger1", {
  methods: ["GET"],
  route: "api/{*segments}",
  handler: async (context, request) => {
    console.log("context ::::: ", context);
    console.log("request :::::: ", request);

    return { body: `Hello` };
  },
});

module.exports = azureFunctionHandler(expressApp);
```

app.ts

```
import express, { Request, Response } from "express";
const app = express();

app.get("/api/user", (req: Request, res: Response) => {
  res.send("Hello from Express!");
});

export default app;
```

my express app

I'm trying to execute express js APIs from azure function , seems i got the response from azure function like 'Hello' but I expected the response from express like "Hello from Express!".

Comment: Can you please share your project folder structure

Comment: /dist
/node_modules
src/functions/httpTrigger1.ts
app.ts
host.json
local.settings.json
package-lock.json
package.json
tsconfig.json

Comment: so its a typescript or javascript function?

Comment: can you please share a screenshot of your project folder structure

Comment: it is Typescript

Comment: Screenshot  : https://drive.google.com/file/d/1JzT29C5ZNAYHO_zDyyslFa9kb8jiwGUk/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Can you please share your tsconfig file

Comment: {
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "commonjs",
    "target": "es6",
    "outDir": "dist",
    "rootDir": ".",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "strict": false,
    "esModuleInterop": true
  }
}

Comment: Node version is v20.11.1

Comment: Can you try doing [this](https://i.imgur.com/mQjQOsG.png)

Comment: I tried , But I got this error https://imgur.com/a/oKVJJZL

Comment: Please check my code : https://file.io/Y6S0UyfmCbq7

Comment: it looks like a limitation in V4 model where as it works fine for V3 model both in javascript and typescript function

Comment: Yes I have tried in v3 but not able to get response from express.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**`azure-aws-serverless-express`** works perfectly fine for both Javascript and Typescript V3 model Azure function.

**Typescript V3 function**-

**index.ts**-

```
import { AzureFunction, Context, HttpRequest } from "@azure/functions";
import azureFunctionHandler from "azure-aws-serverless-express";
import expressApp from "../app";

const httpTrigger: AzureFunction = function (context: Context, req: HttpRequest) {
     azureFunctionHandler(expressApp)(context, req);
};

export default httpTrigger;
```

**app.ts**-

```
import express, { Request, Response } from "express";
const app = express();

app.get('/api/user', (req,res) => res.send("Hello from Express!"));

export default app;
```

**function.json**-

```json
{
  "bindings": [
    {
      "authLevel": "anonymous",
      "type": "httpTrigger",
      "direction": "in",
      "name": "req",
      "methods": [
        "get",
        "post"
      ],
      "route": "{*segments}"
    },
    {
      "type": "http",
      "direction": "out",
      "name": "res"
    }
  ],
  "scriptFile": "../dist/HttpTrigger1/index.js"
}
```

- I am able to get the expected response.

[image]

[image]

- Where as for V4 model, it keeps complaining about `The "url" argument must be of type string. Received undefined` after passing the Url in string format. This error is referring to the package folder.

[image]

- AFAIK,  **azure-aws-serverless-express** is not yet compatible with V4 models.

Comment: I got response from express in v3 , At the same time I need to check in v4 too. And Thanks for your assist.